# kotlin reflect and vararg

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to replace Java with kotlin, But there are problems with the transmission of vararg.

**test passed in java**

```
public class ExampleUnitTest1 {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        a(1, 2);
    }

    public void a(Object... args) {
        b(args);
    }

    public void b(Object... args) {
        Class clazz1 = ExampleUnitTest1.class;
        try {
            Method method = clazz1.getMethod("add", Integer.class, Integer.class);
            method.invoke(this, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void add(Integer a, Integer b) {
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
}
```

**but test failed in kotlin**

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        a(1, 2)
    }

    fun a(vararg args: Any) {
        b(args)
    }

    fun b(vararg args: Any) {
        val clazz1 = ExampleUnitTest::class.java
        val method = clazz1.getMethod("add", Int::class.java, Int::class.java)
        method.invoke(this, args) // also failed to replace with args[0]
    }

    fun add(a: Int, b: Int) {
        println(a + b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please separate this question in to 2, one about reflection, and one about vararg.

Comment: You are trying to use Java reflection with Kotlin code. It's probable that Int::class.java does not match Kotlin's Int because Kotlin will use Java's primitive types for non-null values. I would recommend that you use Kotlin's reflection with Kotlin code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to replace `b(args)` with `b(*args)` and `method.invoke(this, args)` with `method.invoke(this, *args)`. `*` is the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs), which can be used to explode an array of size `n` (in this case `args`) to varargs of size `n`.

This is needed, because you may just as well want to pass in the array called `args` as the one and only parameter instead of its contents. I'm not sure if the Java code is broken as well, but the test passes due to the `catch`-block.

By the way, please describe the error you're facing in more detail next time. State what problem you actually have and which behavior you're expecting instead of just giving us some code.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely，This is the first time I use stack overflow. and my English was so bad that I couldn't articulate the issue.

Comment: @like No explanation is never better than a not ideal one